How to avoid Stripe reverse payment after approval
stripe block payment after approval
I am using stripe for handling payments in my web app
and using radar to block incorrect data like incorrect zip code or CVC
the flow is as follow:

user give us the credit card details and we create a card token with this data in the frontend side.
we create a stripe customer using customer email and user id.
we create a stripe card (card_xxx) using customer and token. this card can be used multiple times by the user.

we hope that if the cvc is incorrect or zip code is incorrect radar should return an error and the card should not be created

we use the card as a source for creating a charge (ch_xxx) and take with capture field set to true

also we hope that if the  CVC is incorrect or zip code is incorrect radar should return an error and the charge should not be created
this is how we create a charge object in our code

func (a *stripePaymentHandler) CardCharge(ctx context.Context, stripeCardID model.StripeCardID, customerID model.CustomerID, amount *money.Money, description string) (model.PaymentReference, *stripe.Charge, error) {
    chargeParams := &stripe.ChargeParams{
        Params: stripe.Params{
            Context: ctx,
        },
        Amount:      stripe.Int64(amount.Amount()),
        Currency:    stripe.String(amount.Currency().Code),
        Capture:     stripe.Bool(true),
        Customer:    stripe.String(string(customerID)),
        Description: stripe.String(description),
    }
    chargeParams.SetSource(string(stripeCardID))


    charge, err := a.api.Charges.New(chargeParams)
    if err != nil {
        return "", nil, err
    }
    return model.PaymentReference(charge.ID), charge, nil
}

The following 2 scenarios are happening:
 Happy scenario for incorrect zip code
In step 3 if the user enter invalid zip code the user can't continue creating card and can't continue payment flow.
 Sad scenario for incorrect zip code
in step 3 even if user enter invalid zip code the user can continue the payment flow
and (card_xxx) object is created then customer continues to step 4 and the amount is authorized but stripe radar blocks the payment and the amount is held for few days.
The problem is customers complaining that the amount is held even if the transaction is failed
From stripe docs here 
When Stripe blocks a payment, it obtains initial authorization from the card issuer but refrains from charging the card. This precaution helps prevent potential fraudulent payments that might lead to disputes.

For some card types, customers might see the card issuer’s authorization for the payment amount on their statement. However, Stripe hasn’t charged this amount or withdrawn funds. The card issuer typically removes this authorization from the customer’s statement within a few days.

here is a sample of charge object  with outcome field
{
  "id": "ch_xxxxxxxxxx",
  "object": "charge",
  "amount": 26825,
  "amount_captured": 0,
  "amount_refunded": 0,
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": "cus_xxxxxxx",
  "outcome": {
    "network_advice_code": null,
    "network_decline_code": null,
    "network_status": "reversed_after_approval",
    "reason": "requested_block_on_incorrect_zip",
    "rule": "block_if_wrong_zip",
    "seller_message": "You requested that Stripe block payments (like this one) for which the customer-entered zip/postal code does not match the code on file with the card-issuing bank.",
    "type": "blocked"
  },
  "paid": false,
  "payment_intent": null,
  "payment_method": "card_xxxxxxxxxx",
  "payment_method_details": {
    "card": {
      "amount_authorized": 26825,
      "authorization_code": "749118",
      "brand": "mastercard",
      "checks": {
        "address_line1_check": null,
        "address_postal_code_check": "fail",
        "cvc_check": "pass"
      },
      "country": "US",
      "exp_month": 12,
      "exp_year": 2028,
      "extended_authorization": {
        "status": "disabled"
      },
      "fingerprint": "xxxxxxxxx",
      "funding": "debit",
      "incremental_authorization": {
        "status": "unavailable"
      },
      "installments": null,
      "last4": "1234",
      "mandate": null,
      "multicapture": {
        "status": "unavailable"
      },
      "network": "mastercard",
      "network_token": {
        "used": false
      },
      "overcapture": {
        "maximum_amount_capturable": 26825,
        "status": "unavailable"
      },
      "three_d_secure": null,
      "wallet": null
    },
    "type": "card"
  },
  "refunded": false,
  "refunds": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/charges/ch_xxxxxxxx/refunds"
  },
  "source": {
    "id": "card_xxxxxxxxxx",
    "object": "card",
    "address_zip": "XXXXX",
    "address_zip_check": "fail",
    "brand": "MasterCard",
    "country": "US",
    "customer": "cus_xxxxxxxx",
    "cvc_check": "pass",
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "exp_month": 12,
    "exp_year": 2028,
    "fingerprint": "xxxxxxxx",
    "funding": "debit",
    "last4": "1234",
    "metadata": {},
    "name": "",
    "tokenization_method": null,
    "wallet": null
  },
  "source_transfer": null,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
  "status": "failed",
  "transfer_data": null,
  "transfer_group": null
}

I am asking if there is a way to avoid this behavior where customers might see the card issuer’s authorization for the payment amount on their statement.
may be there is a better flow or a way to check the postal code before authorizing the amount or what is the best practice to avoid this.
I tried to read stripe docs but they are not telling us what to do to avoid this behavior.

This is a legacy flow. You should use the SetupIntent flow to verify the card, so Stripe will check the zip code at the setup time.
